# Error: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: linux, cakephp

I have written this code

```
    $ips = preg_split("/,/", $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);
    $ip = $ips[0];
    if ($key === $ip && $val === env('SERVER_ADDR')) {
        $addr = env($ip);
        if ($addr !== null) {
            $val = $addr;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting following error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
```

Answer (score 3):

Just dont use array keys without knowing for sure they always exist..
basic PHP one o' one

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
    // now only try to access this key
}
```

The alternative in Cake is to use wrapper methods that are designed to automatically check on the existence internally. Then you can just read the value directly. In your case env() checks on those server vars:

```
$result = env('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
```